# Android Custom ListView

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Я описал Custom ListView для GET запроса, чтобы имя и название города было на одной строке, но результат остается не такой. Что именно не так? Подскажите пожалуйста.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {



private EditText editText;
private ArrayList<String> addresses = new ArrayList<String>();
private ListView listView;
//ArrayList<Currency> products = new ArrayList<Currency>();
BoxAdapter boxAdapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
    //ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    //actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    // создаем адаптер
    boxAdapter = new BoxAdapter(this, addresses);


    // настраиваем список
    ListView lvMain = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    lvMain.setAdapter(boxAdapter);

}



private void refreshAdapter(){
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,addresses);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
public void loadGetBtnClicked(View v){
    CallWebServiceGet callWebServiceGet = new CallWebServiceGet(this);
    //callWebServiceGet.execute("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select+*+from+yahoo.finance.xchange+where+pair+=+%22USDRUB,EURRUB%22&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=");
    //callWebServiceGet.execute("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=12.823539,80.219490");
    callWebServiceGet.execute("http://androiddocs.ru/api/friends.json");

}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_http_get_example, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement

   if (id == android.R.id.home){
        finish();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
private class CallWebServiceGet extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    public CallWebServiceGet(Context context){
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context,"Loading","About to connect to server");
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog.setMessage("Almost ready to connect with server..Doing pre checks");
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        progressDialog.setMessage("Connected to server..Please wait while we fetch results");
        String url = params[0];
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = null;
        try {
            httpGet = new HttpGet(new URI(url));
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet); // time taking process
            InputStream inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"UTF-8"),2*1024);
            String line = null;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        editText.setText(s);
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
            //JSONObject resultsObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("friends");
            //JSONObject resultOb = resultsObject.getJSONObject("results");
            JSONArray  resultArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("friends");

            addresses = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i<resultArray.length(); i++){

               addresses.add(resultArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
                Log.d("DTA",resultArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));



            }
            for (int j = 0; j<resultArray.length(); j++){
                addresses.add(resultArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("city"));
                Log.d("DTA",resultArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("city"));
            }

            refreshAdapter();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Это мой адаптер

```
public class BoxAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private static ArrayList addresses;
Context ctx;
LayoutInflater lInflater;


BoxAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> products) {
    ctx = context;
    addresses = products;

    lInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return addresses.size();

}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
    }

    Currency p = getProduct(position);
    TextView title2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvName); // title
    String song = addresses.get(position).toString();
    title2.setText(song);
    System.out.println(title2);

    TextView title22 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice); // notice
    String song2 = addresses.get(position).toString();
    title22.setText(song2);
    System.out.println(title22);

    return view;
}

Currency getProduct(int position) {
        return ((Currency) getItem(position));
    }

}
```

На всякий MainActivity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">
```

И item.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="20sp">
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPrice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:text="">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Тексты в двух `TextView` не умещаются в одну строку?

Во-первых, в `refreshAdapter()` используется `ArrayAdapter` а не обновляется `BoxAdapter`.

Во-вторых, *item.xml* можно переделать таким образом, указав "вес" и количество занимаемых строк

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text=""
        android:lines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textSize="20sp">
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPrice"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:lines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:text="">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: По логам, он даже не перемещал

Comment: в 'refreshAdapter()' заменил boxAdapter вместо adapter, но при запросе теперь вообще ничего не показывает, но в логах GET запрос сработал